AutoComplete composable, unable to type while popup is visible
I'm making an AutoComplete composable function based on this answer. After fixing a facepalm issue with my code, I am still not quite getting the behavior I wish. The user should be able to type in a text field and a popup will appear below it with suggestions based on what they have typed so far. However, when the suggestions popup, I am unable to type into the text field at all.
Here is the code for my AutoComplete() composeable:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AutoComplete(
    labelText: String,
    options: List<String>,
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val filterOpts = options.filter { it.contains(value, ignoreCase = true) }

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }) {
        TextField(
            label = { Text(text = labelText) },
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            modifier = modifier.menuAnchor(),
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
        )
        if (!filterOpts.isEmpty()) {
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
                filterOpts.forEach { option ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = option) },
                        onClick = {
                            onValueChange(option)
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is an example that uses it to illustrate the problem:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteExample() {
    Scaffold(topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("AutoCompleteExample") }) }) { innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            val names = listOf("Tony Stark", "Steve Rogers", "Bruce Banner", "Natasha Romanoff")
            var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

            AutoComplete(
                labelText = "Name",
                options = names,
                value = name,
                onValueChange = { name = it },
            )
        }
    }
}

I put it in a Scaffold and a Column to prevent any funky layout issues.
Here's a screenshot of what I get. What do I need to modifiy to allow typing in the text field of the AutoComplete?


After revisiting this, I've found that the issue seems to be with the emulator. When I run my app and type on my computer's keyboard, nothing happens. But if I type on the virtual keyboard on the emulator, it works fine.

When the dropdown is open, it takes the focus. This is why you can't type in the text field while the dropdown is visible. And, I don't see a way to change this behavior.
I've created a simple autocomplete text field that should work well for your needs. In this example, the dropdown menu doesn't close when you click outside of it, but you can adjust it if you want that functionality.
@Composable
fun AutoComplete(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    options: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {

    var filteredOpts by remember { mutableStateOf(options) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
    ){
        TextField(
            value = value,
            label = label,
            onValueChange = {
                onValueChange(it)

                filteredOpts = options.filter { option ->
                    option.contains(it)
                }
            },
        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color(242, 237, 247))
        ) {
            filteredOpts.forEach { option ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(text = option) },
                    onClick = {
                        onValueChange(option)

                        filteredOpts = emptyList()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun AutoCompleteTest() {
    Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        val options = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux")

        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        AutoComplete(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
            value = text,
            onValueChange = { text = it },
            options = options,
            label = { Text(text = "Name") }
        )
    }
}

Demo:


Is the difference that you use Column instead of ExposedDropDownMenu?

This solves the immediate problem that I asked about, but it still isn't entirely useable because it doesn't act quite the same as AutoCompleteTextView from view-based Android apps.

Yes! ExposedDropDownMenu takes focus when expanded, so you can't edit the text while it's open.

I just provided some starting code to work with, and you can customize it further to fit your needs.
